# Make contenteditable="true" div have valid and invalid state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the required attribute doesn't work on div with contentEditable ="true".Is there any way to make the field required so that div would have a valid and invalid state?

Comment: With simply HTML5, no as it's strictly not form element. You would use JS to check if the div has no content and display an invalid state from that.

Comment: how will I set the state to the div element using javascript/jquery because I have to apply css to the div based on their valid and invalid state

Comment: This isn't a tutorial service... please research on how to check if a given element has no value/content. Give it an attempt and post back if you get stuck with an actual code issue as a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the following script that allows you to use the `required` attribute:

```
const selectors = document.querySelectorAll('div[contenteditable="true"][required]');

for (let selector of selectors) {
  selector.addEventListener('input', () => {
    if (selector.innerHTML === '') {
      selector.style.border = '2px solid red';
      selector.classList.add('content-invalid');
    }
    else {
      selector.style.border = 0;
      selector.classList.remove('content-invalid');
    }
  })
}
```

Assuming you have a form that should not be submitted if a value is missing:

```js
const selectors = document.querySelectorAll('div[contenteditable="true"][required]');

for (let selector of selectors) {
  selector.addEventListener('input', () => {
    if (selector.innerHTML === '') {
      selector.style.border = '2px solid red';
      selector.classList.add('content-invalid');
    }
    else {
      selector.style.border = 0;
      selector.classList.remove('content-invalid');
    }
  })
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => { 
  if (document.querySelector('.content-invalid')) {
   e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<form action=""> 
  <div contenteditable="true" required>Hello</div>
  <div contenteditable="true" required>World</div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist using `div` tag to get the text, try and look for the `$('div').text()` to get the text you wanted. Do futher parsing such as `parseInt()` if you want the data type to be an integer type.

To do further validations I stand with what has ProEvilz has commented which is to discover yourself since you are the only one who understand and know what to be validated